# HTML in codenameone TextArea

Tags: codenameone

I want to highlight some text with various colors and fonts in the textArea.
I use HTML in my java desktop applications. How is this accomplished in codenameone?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something we can port efficiently to devices. If you just want to view rich text there is this [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html) but if you want to edit rich text then the best approach would be to use a `BrowserComponent` and launch one of the standard JavaScript rich text editors within that component. That's pretty heavy though so I suggest using it only if you actually need it.